# Corridos staccato eightnotes or 16th notes?

Tags: notation, bass-guitar, staccato, rests

*La mesa del rincon* is a song I am transcribing bass for. It is by Los tigres Del Norte.

I am wondering if it is ok to use staccato eighth notes for the bass part, or are they actually supposed to be sixteenth notes? I am just confused as whether the bass notes should be written as staccato eighth notes or sixteenth notes for these kinds of songs.

I've read online that if you want a note to be a specific length you use the appropriate note followed by rest. So instead of using the staccato eighth note, am I actually supposed to be using 16ths followed by rests?